# Auto completando input com endereço

Tags: javascript, html

Existe alguma API que quando ao digitar o nome de uma cidade por exemplo, aparecera a sugestão como o nome da cidade em baixo do formulário? Por favor, não mandem o Place Autocompleter do Google, preciso de um API que forneça a sugestão da cidade e estado, exemplo:

- Santos, SP

Comment: Aqui tem uma [lista de estados](https://bitbucket.org/mgibsonbr/difutils/src/d9fcb06decee044a1c5cb638b2168eb0fcb14926/difutils_info/brasil_estados.json?at=default) e uma [lista de cidades](https://bitbucket.org/mgibsonbr/difutils/src/d9fcb06decee044a1c5cb638b2168eb0fcb14926/difutils_info/brasil_cidades.json?at=default) em formato JSON. É meio grandinha pra usar no lado cliente, mas se der uma "enxugada" nela deve dar pra usar. Eu sugeriria uma solução mais completa (sou o autor da biblioteca linkada), mas não tenho nada que funcione exclusivamente no browser (só integrada ao Django).

Comment: Nota: essa lista foi tirada de fontes públicas, mas não me lembro exatamente de onde. Infelizmente, os nomes das cidades estão sem acentuação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já usou jquery?

site: [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

Licença: https://jquery.org/license/

Um exemplo de AutoComplete.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 2):

Veja [Link](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete).

**Exemplo:**

```
var cidades = [
           { data: 'es_afonso_claudio', value: 'Afonso Cláudio - ES' },
           { data: 'es_alegre', value: 'Alegre - ES' },
           { data: 'es_alfredo_chaves', value: 'Alfredo Chaves - ES' },
           { data: 'es_alto_rio_novo', value: 'Alto Rio Novo - ES' },
        ]

$('#cidades').autocomplete({
            lookup: cidades,
            onSelect: function(suggestion){
                alert(suggestion.value  + ' : ' + suggestion.data);
            }
        });
```

No caso aqui `#cidade`s é o *ID* do *input* text.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, dê uma olhada no [Twitter Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

É um componente de autocompletar que permite a inclusão de dados `default` que são enviados na página para acesso rápido.

Recomendo conhecer!